# Embedded Watson Assistant instance to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Is there a way to integrate Watson Assistant to a Wordpress website like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rG0EtLRx1Y) video? I've been looking at the API reference but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Wordpress plugin for Watson Assistant](https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/). It allows to have a chatbot displayed on specified Wordpress pages. It can be installed via the plugin page by searching for "Watson Assistant".

Answer (score 0):

Use our product Kommunicate which provides Wordpress Chatbot plugin https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/chatbot-for-wordpress/

and connects with Watson Assistant
https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/ibm-watson-chatbot/